# Terragrunt Linter

Tags: terraform, linting, terragrunt

I'm having troubles using HCL files at VSCode. When I open the HCL file the indentations are messy. So I fix it and close the file, when I open again...messy again...
Someone know a add-ons to works with HCL files?

The official [Terraform from Hachicorp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform) not works, because I'm using Terragrunt Syntax.
I tried too the another called [Hashicorp HCL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wholroyd.HCL), but the bugs continues...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until an add-on will be available, you can run this:

This will recursively search the current working directory for any folders that contain Terragrunt configuration files and run the equivalent of terraform fmt on them.

```
terragrunt hclfmt
```

Or this, to format a sepcific file:

```
terragrunt hclfmt --terragrunt-hclfmt-file /path/to/hcl/file
```

https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/configuration/

**Take it one step further:**

1. Install Run on Save -
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave
2. Add the follwoing config to *settings.json*

```json
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "match": "\\.hcl$",
            "cmd": "terragrunt hclfmt --terragrunt-hclfmt-file ${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now every time you will save `.hcl` file, the `terragrunt hclfmt` command will run and reformat that file.

Note - if you have auto save enabled, it will run automatically every time you make a change to `.hcl` file.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is only one extension for Visual Studio Code which highlights Terragrunt - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=4ops.terraform

It is better than nothing.

---

You can also format Terragrunt configurations before git commit automatically using [pre-commit](https://www.pre-commit.com/) and [such config](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/meta/blob/master/.pre-commit-config.yaml).

Comment: Thanks bro! Works to me, but was necessary delete my ~/.vscode/ probably some weird thing there.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out that there is now an [official HashiCorp Visual Studio Code extension for HCL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.HCL).

I was also looking for support for HCL syntax in Visual Studio Code and many extensions produced conflicts or were not further in development. Luckily I found the proper extension in a GitHub discussion about this same topic, if you are curious [this is the thread.](https://github.com/hashicorp/vscode-terraform/issues/639)
More details in the official HashiCorp [blog post announcing the extension](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/announcing-the-hcl-extension-for-visual-studio-code-0-1).

Enjoy and happy coding.

Comment: That extension does not really support the terragrunt.hcl